# Calculations of standard errors

Tags: probability, statistics, solution-verification, confidence-interval, standard-error

**Problem**

Let $Y_1 \sim N(μ_1,1),Y_2 \sim N(μ_2,1), Y_3 \sim N(μ_3,1)$ and also assume that these three random variables are mutually independent. The observed sample values are $y_1 = 2, y_2 = 0 \ \mathrm{and} \ y_3 = −1$, respectively. We are interested in doing inference on the parameter $$\theta = 0.1\mu_1 + 0.2\mu_2 + 0.7\mu_3,$$ where $\theta$ is a weighted average of the population means. Now, suppose that $μ_2 = 0$ and $μ_3 = 0$ are known. Derive an exact upper range $90\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$ taking this additional information into account.

**My answers**

**Method 1**

Let $$\overline{Y} = 0.1Y_1 + 0.2Y_2 + 0.7Y_3.$$ We have
$$\begin{aligned}
Var(\overline{Y}) & = 0.1^2 Var(Y_1) + 0.2^2 Var(Y_2) + 0.7^2 Var(Y_3) \\
& = \frac{27}{50} \\
\end{aligned}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(\overline{Y}) & = 0.1 \mathbb{E} (Y_1) + 0.2 \mathbb{E} (Y_2) + 0.7  \mathbb{E} (Y_3)\\
& = 0.1 \mu_1 + 0.2 \mu_2 + 0.7 \mu_3 \\
& = \theta \\ 
\implies \overline{Y} & \sim N \left( \theta , \frac{27}{50} \right)
\end{aligned}$$
Thus, the exact upper range $90\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$ is $$\left( 0.1 \mu_1 + 0.2 \mu_2 + 0.7 \mu_3 - Z \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} , \infty \right),$$
but since we know $\mu_2 = 0 = \mu_3$, and from the sample, an estimate of $\mu_1 = 2$, we have $$\left(0.2 - 1.282 \sqrt{\frac{27}{50}}, \infty \right)$$

**Method 2**

Since $\mu_2 = 0 = \mu_3$, so $\theta$ reduces to $0.1 \mu_1$.

Redefine $$\overline{Y} = 0.1Y_1.$$

We have
$$\begin{aligned}
Var(\overline{Y}) & = 0.1^2 Var(Y_1) \\
& = 0.01 \\
\end{aligned}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(\overline{Y}) & = 0.1 \mathbb{E} (Y_1) \\
& = 0.1 \mu_1 \\
& = \theta \\ 
\implies \overline{Y} & \sim N (\theta , 0.01)
\end{aligned}$$
Thus, the exact upper range $90\%$ confidence interval for $\theta$ is $$\left( 0.1 \mu_1 - Z \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}, \infty \right)$$
and, since we know, from the sample, an estimate of $\mu_1 = 2$, we have $$(0.2 - 1.282 \sqrt{0.01}, \infty)$$

As I have just covered confidence intervals, I am uncertain whether method $1$ or method $2$ is correct. In particular, the standard error I obtained from each method is different. Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You considered two different estimators of $\theta$. It's therefore perfectly normal to get two different standard error. In fact, it's coherent that you get a lower standard error using the second method since in the first method you are pretty much trying to estimate $\mu_1$ using $y_2$ and $y_3$ which comes from distributions not depending on $\mu_1$. The quantities $y_1$ and $y_2$ don't help estimating $\mu_1$ and thus only adds noise to your estimator which worsen its standard deviation. This explains why the second method works better.